# Which one of the following statement holds for every analytics functions $f : T \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $T$ be the closed units  disk and dT  be the  unit circle. Then  which one of the following statement holds  for  every analytics   functions $f : T \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

a) $|f|$ attains  its  minimum and its  maximum on dT

b) $|f|$ attains  its  minimum  on dT but need  not attains its  maximum on dT

c) $|f|$ attains  its  maximum  on dT but need  not attains its  minimum on dT

d) $ |f|$ need  not attains  its maximum on dT and also it need not attains its  minimum on dT

My attempts : By maximum modulus  Theorem...option  C will be  True

Is it correct ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right.

Let me give you a different approach. You can reject the other choices by taking say $f(z)=z$, i.e. identity function.

$|f(z)|$ has maximum value $1$ which it attains on the boundary  and has minimum value zero which it attains on the center of the disk.

So $a,b,d$ are false.

Comment: The example shows that (a) and (b) are false; the theorem shows that (b) and (d) are false.  You need both to be sure that (c) is true.